# CSS - prevent :hover during animation?

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I have a `<div>` that plays an animation. I want to prevent `div:hover` from taking effect on that `<div>` while the animation is still playing.

For example:

```
<div></div>
```

```css
div:before {
    content: "A";
    -webkit-animation: A 5s;
    -moz-animation:    A 5s;
    animation:         A 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes A {
     100% { font-size: 5em; }
}

@-moz-keyframes A {
     100% { font-size: 5em; }
}

@keyframes A {
    100% { font-size: 5em; }
}

div:hover:before { 
    content: "B";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hh54D/

In this example, the animation increases the size of the letter "A". But if you hover the animation, `div:hover` changes it to letter "B". I would like to stop this from happening - in other words, *if* hovered it should still remain the letter "A" until the animation is finished. How should this be done in CSS?

Comment: You can use [preventdefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault)

Comment: preventDefault will cancel the JS event rather than prevent the CSS pseudo class style rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Jquery if you don't mind.
For transition:

```
$("#YourDivID").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function(){change div content to B});
```

For annimation:

```
$("#YourDivID").bind("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){change div content});
```

You can also just use pure js:

```
element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("animationend", callfunction,false);
element.addEventListener("oanimationend", callfunction,false);
```

You can read [this post](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end)