# Disabling :hover during Css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have got a sidebar nav that when the page loads, it slides out of the screen, and then when the user hovers over the area, the nav slides back on screen. However, when the nav slides off, if the user hovers over the nav during the slide off animation, the nav starts to flicker in and out as it tries to do both animations. I am wondering if there is a way to prevent this and/or disable the :hover during the slide out animation?

Sidebar asp.net

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar slider"> 
     <h5 style="font-family: Helvetica; text-transform: uppercase">Releases</h5>
     <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="releaseStatusFilter" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="6" Height="5" style="margin-left:-10px">
     <asp:ListItem Text="Future" Value ="Future" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Current" Value ="Current" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
     <asp:ListItem Text="Completed" Value ="Completed" Selected="false"></asp:ListItem></asp:CheckBoxList>
     <script type="text/javascript"></script>
     <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="releaseList" style="float:left;">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <ul class="nav navbar nav-sidebar goo-collapsible" >
                 <li><a href='<%# "Release.aspx?rn="+ Eval("releaseNumber") %>'><%# Eval("releaseNumber") + " " + Eval("releaseShortName") %></a></li>
             </ul>
             <script type="text/javascript">
                 var param = location.search.split('rn=')[1]
                 param = param.split('%20').join(' ')
                 $('ul').find('a[href="Release.aspx?rn=' + param + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
             </script>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

css

```
.sidebar {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidebar {
        font-size: 12px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 120px;
        width: 175px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0px;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto; /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        -webkit-animation: bannermoveout 0.5s linear both;
        animation: bannermoveout 0.5s linear both;
    }
}

@keyframes bannermoveout {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate3d(-92px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-185px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bannermoveout {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate3d(-92px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-185px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
}

.sidebar:hover {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 0.5s linear both;
    animation: bannermove 0.5s linear both;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(-185px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate3d(-92px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(-185px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate3d(-92px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    }
}
```

So i managed to fix it by using jquery to animate the sidebar menu instead of css. Thanks everyone for you help!

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".slider").animate({
                left: '-185px'
            }, "fast")
            $("#slidebody").animate({
                left: '0px'
            }, "fast")
            .queue(function () {
                $(".slider").hover(function () {
                    $(".slider").stop().animate({ left: '0px' });
                    $("#slidebody").stop().animate({ left: "60px" });
                    $(this).dequeue();
                }, function() {
                    $(".slider").stop().animate({ left: '-185px' });
                    $("#slidebody").stop().animate({ left: "0px" });
                });
            });
        });
```

**The slidebody tag was just so that i can shift the container so that the nav didnt overlap the container. **

Comment: Maybe this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372748/css-prevent-hover-during-animation

Comment: I tried that initally, but it didnt work.

Comment: Can include `html` , `css` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: Well you tagged it also as jQuery, so you could go for `.queue`method https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Comment: Review the asp.net file you have a line with  `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` that you can delete

Comment: @sergiodebcn ya that was there for when i was testing a few codes.

Comment: I'd use a specific class to prevent any hover issues (via JS), but have you tried to set `pointer-events: none;` to the keyframe styles?

Comment: Instead of animations, use transitions. It will save you TONS OF WORK and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by using the .stop() function. Check this out : http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Comment: tried that,but it didnt work, just added another 20px to the transition left.

Comment: The `.stop()` method stops all the running **jQuery** animations. And that's it. It won't help in this case.

Comment: @metalviper How did this solved your problem?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel the  link he gave me helped me design the jquery animation i showed above; which solved my issue.

Comment: @metalviper Can't argue with that, but this answer is extremely poor and prone to link rotting. It doesn't even have anything from the link. I think this needs a huge rewrite. But the final decision is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS, rewritten to use transitions (I've removed the `@media`query):

```css
.sidebar {
 font-size: 12px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
 width: 175px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0px;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background-color: #ccc;
 border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;

 /*            v  magic starts there  v               */

 transition: ease-in-out 0.5s transform;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.5s transform;
 transform: translate3d(-185px, 0px, 0px);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-185px, 0px, 0px);
}

.sidebar:hover {
 transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar slider"> 
    <h5 style="font-family: Helvetica; text-transform: uppercase">Releases</h5>
</div>
```

You are hammering a screw! It isn't meant for being nailed, but it gets the job done. But not as well as a nail would.

Transitions were designed for this, and not animations.
Animations are meant to *animate* the element.
Transitions are meant for smoothly *transition* between states.

Besides, this is so much shorter!

---

As an optimization, I would use margins instead.

Like the following:

```css
.sidebar {
 font-size: 12px;
 position: fixed;
 top: 20px;
 width: 175px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background-color: #ccc;
 border-right: 1px solid #eeeeee;

 /*            v  magic starts there  v               */
 
 transition: ease-in-out 0.5s margin-left;
 -webkit-transition: ease-in-out 0.5s margin-left;
 margin-left:-185px;
}


.sidebar:hover {
 margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar slider"> 
    <h5 style="font-family: Helvetica; text-transform: uppercase">Releases</h5>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try unbinding the hover event with jQuery.  When you do this, you're essentially telling the element to no longer respond to an event until you rebind it.  Here's a really general example:

```
//when the animation begins, unbind the hover event
$("sidebar").bind("animationstart", $(".sidebar").unbind("hover"));

//now, when the animation ends, rebind the hover event and call the function (in this case fxn())) that should fire on the hover event 
$("sidebar").bind("animationend", $(".sidebar").bind("hover", fxn));
```

Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, im fairly new to js and jquery. How would i unbind hover when the slide out transition occurs and rebind it when the animation is complete?

Comment: Well, it depends how the animation begins.  I've never used the asp.net sidebar, but the link in @Portekoi's response looked promising.  I'll update my answer to show you what I mean.